# C++ Eigen Library: Cast for fixed sized Matrices

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

following problem:

```
template<int nDim>
void foo ( ){

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> bar;

    if ( nDim == 3 ){
        bar = generate_a_special_3x3_Matrix();}
    else if ( nDim == 2 ){
        bar = generate_a_special_2x2_Matrix();}


// ... further math here 
}
```

So, of course due to the static assertions, this code does not compile.
However, it is guaranteed that at runtime never a problem occurs.

Currently know solutions are assignments via .block(3,3) or via Ref<..> (cf. [Cast dynamic matrix to fixed matrix in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396703/cast-dynamic-matrix-to-fixed-matrix-in-eigen) ).

.block approach:

```
template<int nDim>
void foo ( ){

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> bar;

    if ( nDim == 3 ){
        bar.block(3,3) = generate_a_special_3x3_Matrix();}
    else if ( nDim == 2 ){
        bar.block(2,2)  = generate_a_special_2x2_Matrix();}


// ... further math here 
}
```

However, both approaches involve runtime checks for correct matrix sizes, which are not really necessary, and the written code is not really beautiful.

I don't really care about the runtime overhead (although it would be nice to avoid it), but the written code is not really clean in my eyes, since the intention of .block() is not immediately clear to someone else.
Is there a better approach, e.g. something like a cast?

Edit: Two good solutions were posted (if constexpr), However, i need a C++11/14 compatible approach!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elegantly stick with c++98, you can abuse the [comma initializer](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) syntax:

```
template<int N>
void foo(){
  Eigen::Matrix<double, N, N> bar;
  if(N==3)      bar << Matrix3d();
  else if(N==2) bar << Matrix2d();
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution in the present case! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) from C++17, according to the value of condition, if the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded; then the code won't cause compilation error. e.g.

```
template<int nDim>
void foo () {

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> bar;

    if constexpr ( nDim == 3 ) {
        bar = generate_a_special_3x3_Matrix();
    } else constexpr if ( nDim == 2 ) {
        bar = generate_a_special_2x2_Matrix();
    }

    // ... further math here 
}
```

or make a `generate_a_special_Matrix` function template, e.g.

```
template <int nDim>
Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> generate_a_special_Matrix();

template <>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2> generate_a_special_Matrix<2>() { 
    ... generating ...
    return ...; 
}

template <>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> generate_a_special_Matrix<3>() { 
    ... generating ...
    return ...; 
}
```

then

```
template<int nDim>
void foo () {

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> bar;
    bar = generate_a_special_Matrix<nDim>();

    // ... further math here 
}
```

Comment: Ok, you beat me by a minute (for the templated solution)

Comment: Nice solution, thank you; However, i would prefert to stick to GCC 4.8?

Comment: @macmallow What's the problem of the 2nd solution?

Comment: The second solution is fine, but it somewhat hides the actual operations in a foreign functions and it is not immediately clear what happens in generate_a_special_Matrix<nDim>().

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++17, you can write

```
if constexpr ( nDim == 3 ){ bar = generate_a_special_3x3_Matrix();}
```

etc. But you can easily implement a C++03 compatible solution by templatizing your `generate_a_special_nxn_Matrix` function:

```
// general declaration (without implementation):
template<int nDim>
Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> generate_a_special_nxn_Matrix();
template<>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2> generate_a_special_nxn_Matrix(){
    return generate_a_special_2x2_Matrix();
}
template<>
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> generate_a_special_nxn_Matrix(){
    return generate_a_special_3x3_Matrix();
}
```

And then directly call

```
template<int nDim>
void foo ( ){

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nDim, nDim> bar = generate_a_special_nxn_Matrix<nDim>();

    // ... further math here 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your C++03 would be OK, however, it hides the actual operations and therefore is not really suitable in the present case.

The C++17 approach is nice, but i need to stick to GCC 4.8.